# Please come support the new Noahide.SE proposal

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, stackexchange

**Update:** Unfortunately, the proposal has been closed for failing to meet Stack Exchange's [minimum activity requirements](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20966/minimum-activity-requirements-for-area-51).  But thanks to those of you who followed it.

---

I recently created [a proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/128096/noahide-community) for a "Noahide Community" site.  It is currently in the Definition phase, and I'm looking for followers and example questions so that the proposal can advance.

The goal of this new Noahide.SE site is to provide a specialized environment for self-identified Noahides (non-Jewish monotheists) to discuss and learn the details of the Noahide Laws, as well as getting practical advice for how Noahides should pray, observe holidays, or participate in "religious" lifecycle events such as weddings or funerals.

Noahide.SE will naturally have some overlap in topics with Mi Yodeya, particularly in [noahide-laws](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/noahide-laws), [noahidism](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/noahidism), [gentiles](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gentiles), and perhaps [conversion-to-judaism](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conversion-to-judaism).  The primary difference is that all questions and answers on Noahide.SE will be aimed mostly at a *non*-Jewish audience.  Thus, questions about Jewish-specific mitzvot (e.g., Shabbat observance or Kashrut laws) or the historical experiences of the Jewish people will be off-topic (redirected to Mi Yodeya) unless framed in a way that's relevant to Noahides.

But, provided that all questions are relevant to the target audience, our Jewish friends are certainly welcome to participate.  Your expertise and engagement within the Mi Yodeya community make you an essential part of our efforts.  We invite you to visit the Noahide.SE proposal page, share your thoughts, and consider endorsing the proposal if it aligns with your interests.

Thank you for your time and consideration, and Happy Hanukkah!

Comment: Sounds like a cool idea. Good luck!

Comment: Good luck! I think it's a great idea and one of the best reasons I could think is simply the fact that there is such a group will be a great encouragement for Noahides to support each other.
StackExchange is strict so if it doesn't work out I would suggest going ahead with other platforms like Reddit, etc.

Comment: @larry909 Great suggestion. We'll see how the proposal goes. Do you have any sample questions that might help define the site?

Comment: Other than this one, are there other Stack Exchange sites whose users might be interested in the proposal?

Comment: @PaulWalker I'm not happy the Noachide SE didn't endure... Observant Noachides truly hold a special place in my heart. How can we resolve the closed status?

Comment: @Grapefruit There will probably need to be a coordinated effort off Stack Exchange prior to re-submission. But really, though, if people's questions are being answered on Mi Yodeya, they won't feel a need to make a separate site. That's not necessarily a bad thing.  A Noahide-focused site probably won't have near the amount of Jewish traffic, either.

Comment: We could also just make the noahide tag here more active

Answer (score 1):

The Noahide Community proposal has 9 followers and 14 sample questions posted.

Consider taking a minute to check out the sample questions and post one if you have a question that hasn't shown up yet. You can also vote up or down on the ones already there. The sample questions help define the future site.

Thanks!